# git svn with tags folder within branches folder

Tags: git, svn

I'm currently migrating a SVN repository to Git and run into the following problem with git svn:

```
$ git svn fetch
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/tags': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/tags': 'refs/remotes/origin/tags/REL-2.3.1.1' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/tags'
update-ref -m r3264 refs/remotes/origin/tags 981b12f8d739180b54d280f61a197ba3ae792ad9: command returned error: 128
```

Configuration: use standard layout (`-s`)

The problem is, that SVN revision 3264 adds a folder called `branches\tags` which is very unfortunate. Is there any way to say:

"Standard layout (trunk, branches, tags), BUT all "branches" under `branches\tags` are tags as well"?

Edit: current configuration:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = https://server/svn/projects/myproject
fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

Adding:

```
tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/branches/tags/*
```

does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized that `-s` sets the `branches` folder to `refs/remotes/origin/*`. If I manually change that to `refs/remotes/origin/branches/*` I don't run into name conflicts (branches/tags vs. tags) and after re-running `git svn fetch` from the start, the problem is gone.

Comment: To save time in the future, this can be found in .git/config

Answer (score 0):

> "Standard layout (trunk, branches, tags), BUT all "branches" under
>   branches\tags are tags as well"?

You can not say this and must move tags outside of branches space before conversion (dumping will be more safe, than ordinary `svn mv`, from my POV)